# Windows 7 black screen at login

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I have an HP laptop with two user profiles. My main user profile has started showing me a black screen with a mouse cursor at login which lasts for 2-3 minutes. The other user profile does not have this problem and shows the desktop. How can I compare the login procedure sequences between these two user profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a corrupt user profile. You can try running chkdsk or make a new user profile and transfer all your data over.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem last month. I found out that was because of avast antivirus. I logged in the safe mode and uninstalled the antivirus and the problem ws resolved.

Comment: I even got the black screen in safe-mode. I've used msconfig to clean up a whole bunch of services at start up which seems to have alleviated the problem but I can't say that I identified the exact cause.